# WAMP: WordPress upload error

Tags: php, wordpress, wamp

I really hope someone can help me as i'm stumped.

I'm trying to upload an exported .xml file from one website to a WordPress installation on my localhost WAMP installation.

I am getting this error message:

**Sorry, there has been an error.
File is empty. Please upload something more substantial. This error could also be caused by uploads being disabled in your php.ini or by post_max_size being defined as smaller than upload_max_filesize in php.ini.**

I have checked my php.ini file and this is what it says:

```
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
```

Anyone got any ideas on how to fix this? p.s. The file is not empty.

Thanks.

Comment: Just out of interest, How big is your xml file?

Comment: Is this just a xml file, or one that contains a site backup of your other site.

Comment: just the .xml - I tried with a backup also and an .sql file - all did the same.